# mysql - how to display error instead of throw err in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, ejs

I have put some constraints in my mysql table and thus when a duplicate value is entered, it throws an error and the server shuts down.
What I want instead is that the server should keep running and I should display the error to the end user, so they know they are inputting a duplicate value and hence the error.

how do I do that?

here's my code.
i tried to change the code a bit by putting the render statement in the else option. i.e if it doesnt throw the error then page is rendered otherwise It would do a res.send(err).
is that possible??

here's the code for this

```
connection.query("INSERT INTO attendance_details(month_year,uan,name,days_present,real_basic_salary,other_allowances,gross_salary,ptax) VALUES ?", 
        [finalData], function(err) {
    if (err){
     throw err;
     res.send(err);
 }else{
    var attendanceData = {monthyear :monthFromHTML,rows:rowsLength,uanarr:uanArr,designationarr:designationArr,
        namearr:nameArr,finaldata:finalData,realbasicsalary:realBasicSalary,realgrosssalary:realGrossSalary,ptax:pTax,advance:advance};

    //put database query for inserting values here
    res.render('attendance-data.ejs', attendanceData);
 }
    connection.end();
});
```

Comment: So, basically you want to throw error to client after getting error?

Comment: Yeah, I want them to know that they are trying to put in duplicate entry and that's why getting an error and I want the server to keep running so I can display the error the the client and ask him to try again.

Comment: what in your console.log(err) ?

Comment: well, I didnt console.log it but it said something about duplicate entries. Listen I was testing whether the mysql table constraint works. I didnt want people to be able to enter duplicate entries and that's why I put in the constraint.
therefore, I just want that people should see this error about it being duplicate entries and that they should try again.

Comment: basically I want them to get an error message when they try to enter a duplicate value

Comment: Just remove      throw err;

Comment: how does removing throw err help?